# Do Android Phones and Tabs display websites differently?

Tags: android, jquery, html

I am developing a web application (NOT a mobile App) using jQuery, which will be accessed by a variety of devices such as Android mobiles, tabs and also PCs. For testing, I need to know if testing done on just Android Tabs would be sufficient, or do jQuery web sites display differently on Android Phones compared to tabs?

Comment: They can.  They'll be different dimensions, and different dpi so things will look different.  Follow the general rule of testing-  Murphy's law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site will look different because they are different resolutions on each device. If I use Google Chrome I suggest an extension called "Resize Window" that simulates the resolution change, to give you an idea of ​​how your site will look on different devices (not 100% accurate to the device but if it helps). And if you use Firefox natively brings a tool that serves the same purpose, but I do not remember its name. I hope this helps.